# Convert char array to C++11 unique_ptr for strcpy

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, unique-ptr

Currently I have this code in C++ (I'm using Visual Studio 2013):

```
char * dest= new char[srcLen + 1] {};
strcpy(dest, source);
std::string s(dest);
delete dest;
```

How do I convert this to a C++11 `unique_ptr` using `make_unique` so that it's usable by `strcpy()`?

I tried:

```
auto dest = make_unique<char>(srcLen + 1);
strcpy(dest, source);
```

However, I'm getting the following compile error on the `strcpy` line

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'char *strcpy(char *,const char *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::unique_ptr<char,std::default_delete<char>>' to 'char *'
```

**Update** I do use a `std::string`. I've updated my code snippet to make it more clear. Basically, the source char * array may or may not be null terminated. The temporary `dest` buffer ensures that the string is null-terminated. I do want to convert it to a `std::string`. What I had before works. I just wanted to know if there's a way to create the temp buffer using `make_unique` so that there will be no need for `new` and `delete`.

Comment: I'm interested in hearing more about the thought processes that led you to the decision to use a `std::unique_ptr` for this.

Comment: I've updated my post to explain my reasoning. Thanks.

Comment: Still doesn't explain why you were using `new`/`delete` for this, and why you're using `std::unique_ptr` for it now. Oh well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess I was trying to see if it made sense to create dynamic char arrays using `unique_ptr` seeing that I won't have to worry about deleting it, but I guess not.

Comment: It makes sense to replace `new`/`delete` with `std::unique_ptr`, yes, but I doubt `new`/`delete` was appropriate for your problem in the first place, and moving to `std::unique_ptr` just takes you further down that wrong path. Why not just construct a `std::string` from the original data and be done with it? Manually strip off the optional null terminator after-the-fact, if you need to.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, thanks. Only after this exchange I found out I can directly create a `std::string` from a non-null terminated char array by passing in the length of the source buffer as the second parameter like this: `std::string str(source, srcLen)`.

Comment: That's right. As I said an hour or so ago in my answer, _the documentation is your friend_ and you should definitely treat it as such (i.e. **read it**!!!!)

Answer (score 6):

**Don't.**

Use a `std::string`, the type designed for wrapping dynamically-allocated `char` arrays.

More generally, you may access the underlying pointer of a `std::unique_ptr` with the `T* std::unique_ptr<T>::get() const` member function:

```
strcpy(dest.get(), source);
```

Also, you have a bug in that all you're doing with `dest` right now is creating a single dynamically-allocated `char`, with initial value `srcLen`. Whoops!

As always, *[the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is your friend* and you should definitely treat it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I needed to convert some old code to use `std::string` but it's got tie-ins from lots of other functions so I can't just completely refactor everything.  At a certain point, I'm stuck dealing with the string as a char array.

The solution I found was to make a unique pointer to a char[] array and `strpy` from the `c_str()` into it.  Obviously I can't use that to update the actual string as it's read-only but that wasn't a requirement.

Here's the code:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> temp_a_local_string(new char[a_local_string.length()+1] {0});

strcpy(temp_a_local_string.get(), a_local_string.c_str());

pa_local_string = temp_a_local_string.get();
```

And from there, `pa_localstring` (which was the original variables) is treated like the old char array.  It goes out of scope pretty soon after, and thus dies the `unique_ptr`.

**I probably should be using `make_unique`, but I'm not super-versed in auto pointers yet.**