# C++/ I have a question about the 'new' method of 'unique_ptr'

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

```
class Manager {
private:
    //char* buff_;
    int buff_size_;
    int* ref_;
    unique_ptr<char> buff_;

public:
    Manager() {
        buff_size_ = 1;
        buff_ = nullptr;
        ref_ = new int;
        *ref_ = 1;
    }
    Manager(const char* s) {
        buff_size_ = strlen(s);
        buff_ = new char[buff_size_ + 1]; //error E0349 no operator = matches these operands
        //strcpy(buff_, s);
        ref_ = new int;
        *ref_ = 1;
    }
}
```

I want to replace `char*` with `unique_ptr`.

How can I write `new` in `Manager(const char*s){}`?

Comment: Are you sure you want `unique_ptr`? Why not `std::string`?

Comment: Probably not a _duplicate_ but [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954415/convert-char-array-to-c11-unique-ptr-for-strcpy) should provide what you need

Comment: Std::string is not used because it is an implementation code for learning :)

Comment: Here is some [documentation for `std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique), a function you should find very helpful.

Comment: Here is some [documentation on the Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), a C++ feature so useful that I'm frequently stunned by how many people don't know how to use it correctly or that it exists at all.

Comment: @아싸아 What is the point of allocating `ref_` dynamically? Why not just use an `int` without dynamic allocation?

Comment: @RemyLebeau obviously it's for demonstrating the pitfalls of having a class with a raw pointer member but no destructor.

Comment: "Std::string is not used because it is an implementation code for learning" -- You're learning things the wrong way around. Learn the proper C++ constructs, like std::string and std::vector, **before** you try your hand at exactly those kinds of hard-to-get-right C constructs they were meant to replace. Ideally, you should not have to deal with naked pointers *at all*.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It was for the reference count. I don't need it anymore. I'm gonna fix it right now

Comment: @아싸아 modern C++ has `std::shared_ptr` for managing reference-counted objects that are created dynamically.

Comment: @RemyLebeau there may be some value in learning the hard way first, so you can appreciate the new stuff properly. Seems kind of sadistic/masochistic though.

Answer (score 3):

First off, since your dynamic `char[]` data is being allocated with `new[]`, you need to declare `buff_` as `unique_ptr<char[]>` instead, so that it will use `delete[]` and not `delete` when freeing the memory.

The assignment `operator=` for `std::unique_ptr` fails in your code because it does not accept a raw pointer, only another `std::unique_ptr` object, or `nullptr`.

Try one of these instead:

```
buff_.reset(new char[buff_size_ + 1]);
```

```
buff_ = std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[buff_size_ + 1]);
```

```
// C++14 and later only
buff_ = std::make_unique<char[]>(buff_size_ + 1);
```

As for `strcpy()`, you can call it with `std::unique_ptr` like this:

```
strcpy(buff_.get(), s);
```

Comment: In this case, should `buff_` be `unique_tr<char>` or `unique_ptr<char[]>`? Or does it matter?

Comment: Thanks !! I wish you all the best today!! 감사합니다 :)

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Yes, it matters. Since the memory is allocated with `new[]`, `buff_` needs to be a `unique_ptr<char[]>` so that it will call `delete[]` and not `delete` when freeing the memory. I have updated my answer. Thanks.